# Изменение элемента по событию "scroll"

Tags: javascript

Коллеги, всем привет.

Вопрос думаю окажется пустяковым для большинства, но я не могу самостоятельно с ним справиться. Прошу вашей помощи.

Задача следующая:
На странице есть header с position: fixed. Необходимо, что бы при скролле от самого верха страницы на 2px вниз к нему добавлялся класс и присутствовал все время. Но, что бы при скролле обратно вверх страницы (только, когда header упирается в верхний край видимой области документа) необходимо, что бы этот класс убирался с элемента.

```
<header class="header">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="header__inner">
            <div class="logo">
               <a class="logo__link" href="#"><img class="logo__img" src="" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="header__menu menu">
               <button class="menu__close-btn"><span class="menu__close-bar"></span></button>
               <nav class="menu__nav nav">
                  <ul class="nav__list">
                     <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link" href="#"></a></li>
                     <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link" href="#"></a></li>
                     <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link" href="#"></a></li>
                     <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link" href="#"></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </nav>
               <button class="menu__btn"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="header__burger burger">
               <button class="burger__btn"><span class="burger__bar"></span></button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот код будет добавлять класс .fixed-header к элементу header, когда пользователь прокручивает страницу на 2 пикселя вниз от самого верха. И этот класс будет удаляться, когда пользователь прокручивает страницу обратно вверх, и header достигнет верхнего края видимой области документа.

```
const header = document.querySelector('.header');
let isScrolled = false;

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  if (scrollTop >= 2 && !isScrolled) {
    header.classList.add('fixed-header');
    isScrolled = true;
  } else if (scrollTop < 2 && isScrolled) {
    header.classList.remove('fixed-header');
    isScrolled = false;
  }
});
```

Переменная isScrolled помогает оптимизировать код, уменьшая количество проверок и действий, выполняемых при каждом событии прокрутки, и это может повысить производительность в случае большого количества событий прокрутки на странице. Если ее убрать, то будет происходить постоянная проверка прокрутки страницы.

Comment: Зачем `isScrolled`?

Comment: Эта переменная служит флагом для определения состояния прокрутки страницы.

Comment: @DovgalDima добавил код. Почему-то "pageYOffset" перечеркивается в редакторе (Visual Studio Code) и ничего не работает, как ожидалось.

Comment: @DovgalDima решил проблему. Все работает. Спасибо большое вам за метод! Очень выручили!

Comment: Рад Был помочь! )))

Answer (score 0):

Можно как-то так

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  const header = document.querySelector('.header');
  if (window.scrollY > 2) {
    header.classList.add('scrolled');
  } else {
    header.classList.remove('scrolled');
  }
});
```

```css
 body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }

 .header {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background: #333;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 10px 0;
   transition: background 0.3s;
 }

 .header.scrolled {
   background: #f00;
 }

 .content {
   height: 2000px;
   /* Для прокрутки страницы */
 }
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__inner">
      <div class="logo">
        <a class="logo__link" href="#"><img class="logo__img" src="" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="header__menu menu">
        <button class="menu__close-btn"><span class="menu__close-bar"></span></button>
        <nav class="menu__nav nav">
          <ul class="nav__list">
            <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link" href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link" href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link" href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link" href="#"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <button class="menu__btn"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="header__burger burger">
        <button class="burger__btn"><span class="burger__bar"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="content"></div>
```

Но, я вам очень не рекомендую этого делать, поскольку вешать отслеживание `scroll` это очень плохая идея, по утечке памяти... Можно там ещё с тротлингом играться, но всё равно плохая идея. Как вариант, возможно ваша задача решиться через CSS и [position: sticky;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)